# Mapping a property to an index column

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to map a List with an index column. This works fine, but I would also like to be able to query the index column from HQL. When I do that [HQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29#Hibernate_Query_Language_.28HQL.29) throws an exception:

> NHibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Position of: component[Location,Time]

To be able to query the WayPoint.Position column from HQL, I have created a Position-property in the WayPoint-class, and I would like to map this property to the Position-column.

I have tried with:

```
wp.Map(x => x.Position).Column("Position");
```

But this results in a MappingException:

> NHibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: Route.WayPoints column: Position

```
public class RouteMap : ClassMap<Route>
{
    private const string LocationKey = "LocationIndex";
    public RouteMap()
    {
        Not.LazyLoad();
        ReadOnly();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Version(x => x.Version);
        Map(x => x.Time);
        References(x => x.StartingPoint).UniqueKey(LocationKey);
        References(x => x.Destination).UniqueKey(LocationKey);
        HasMany(x => x.WayPoints).Component( wp =>
            {
                wp.Map(x => x.Time);
                //wp.Map(x => x.Position).Column("Position");
                wp.Component( wp2 => wp2.Location, gl =>
                    {
                        gl.Map(x => x.Latitude);
                        gl.Map(x => x.Longitude);
                    }
                );
            }

            ).AsList(index => index.Column("Position")).Cascade.All();
    }
}


create table `Route` (
    Id VARCHAR(40) not null,
   Version INTEGER not null,
   Time BIGINT,
   StartingPoint_id VARCHAR(40),
   Destination_id VARCHAR(40),
   primary key (Id),
  unique (StartingPoint_id, Destination_id)
)

create table WayPoints (
    Route_id VARCHAR(40) not null,
   Latitude DOUBLE,
   Longitude DOUBLE,
   Time BIGINT,
   Position INTEGER not null,
   primary key (Route_id, Position)
)
```

Is it possible to map the Position property? Or is there another approach to make HQL aware of the Position-index-field?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to map the Position property at all; if you need to query on the index of a collection, you can do so as follows:

```
select item, index(item) from Order order 
    join order.Items item
where index(item) < 5
```

More information can be found in the [HQL Documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.ReadOnly()` to your `wp.Map(x => x.Position).Column("Position");`  That has allowed me to map multiple properties to the same column before, at least when one of them was a References().

Comment: Readonly() doesn't do it for index columns. There is still a clash. 
Thanks for the answer.